# Starting with Next.js and unable to prevent it from treating my test files as pages within the pages folder

Tags: next.js

I have grown accustomed in my Frontend projects to storing my test files directly next to the components they are testing.

That being said I have started on a project with Next.js and Next.js has a router that is built on the premise of filepath location instead of something like react-router which i've used in the past.

how can i explicitly tell Next.js to ignore my *.spec.ts files?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ### Including non-page files in the pages directory
>
> You can colocate test files or other files used by components in the pages directory. Inside next.config.js, add the pageExtensions config:

```js
module.exports = {
  pageExtensions: ['page.tsx', 'page.ts', 'page.jsx', 'page.js'],
}
```

> Then, rename your pages to have a file extension that includes .page (e.g. rename MyPage.tsx to MyPage.page.tsx). Ensure you rename all Next.js pages, including the files mentioned above.

[Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-page-extensions#including-non-page-files-in-the-pages-directory)

Comment: This sounds like a good solution, look forward to trying it out 

Comment: tell me if it is working so I implement it too with next 13

Comment: it can be a little buggy, i think it breaks the dependency of my _app.txs file and my global styles are messed up, so i'm working on that, but it did do what I need it to. Its a weekend project so i'll have to figure those things out later on this week.